# windows store : webview exception 'navCancelInit is undefined

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am trying to navigate to an website (localy hosted on IIS ) in and  webview control. after loading of homepage (login.aspx)  and successful login it redirects to onother page (userspage.aspx), but as soon as I click on login button it throws an exception "navCancelInit is undefined".

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You must be facing the exception like given below.

[image]

Debug > Options and Settings > Debugging > Just-In-Time > Uncheck "Script":

[image]

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/18/nine-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview.aspx#AN10)